# Django, passing entire object instance when validating through Model validators custom function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a custom validation function for my model in Django as following:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        default=None
    )
company_name = models.CharField(validators=[validate_url],max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
...
```

My validate_url function converts the company_name into an url and checks if the same generated url already exist in any profiles.

```
def validate_url(value):
    url = value.replace(' ', '-')
    url = url.lower()
    try:
        u = Profile.objects.get(url=url)
        raise ValidationError(
            'The company name already exist'
        )
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

This seems to work fine when new profiles are created and saved to the database. However when I'm just editing another fields of an existing profile (through admin), it raises me the validation error from the **validate_url** because it sees himself as already existent value. I would want to pass the user of that instance and check if that user is equal to u.user from u = Profile.objects.get(url=url) and if they are equal it should not raise the error.

The problems is that I cannot simply do that:

```
validators=[validate_url(self.user)]
```

Because it gives me the error that self is not defined. How can I pass the user object instance when validating before saving the profile?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the right use for validators? It is supposed it should only check if  the criteria matchs. I think you should override save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Check here company name, modify ...
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That would work but it won't raise the ValidationError for the specific company_name field. I'm looking for a solution that would do that.